# How can I stop an account from automatically linking with Facebook?

Tags: clash-of-clans, facebook

Is it possible for a friend to use an old account of mine (which I let him use) and connect it with my facebook account, even though I already have another new account linked to that same facebook account?

I seem that when he uses my old account, it will still connect to my facebook. I told him not to link it but it still automatically connects and displaces my new account. How can I stop this from happening?

He has iOS, I have android.

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags when creating a question.

Comment: Did you tried revoking access [(How To)](https://www.facebook.com/help/170585223002660) of Clash of Clans from Facebook? That should stop the app from connecting the old account.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

- Disable linking from Facebook in Clash of Clans (Go to Settings, and you'll find it easily)
- Like @Kovah said, delete the app from Facebook (In the left menu > Applications)

As far as I know, it's the same process whether you're on Android or iOS.